# Inserting one cell value based on the value of another cell

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to insert a currency value in a one cell based on the value of another cell that is using a reference drop down list. Don't seem to be getting the syntax right when using the IF function.

Here's what I tried:

```
=IF(B5=New Course), 25000
```

The B5 cell has several choices based on a drop down reference list. **I'm trying to insert the value of 25000 into cell C5**

Comment: Try `=IF(B5="New Course", 25000,"")`

Answer (score 0):

The function IF() works as following:

```
=IF("Condition to check", "Result if the check is TRUE", "Result if the check is FALSE")
```

Any string in a formula has to go between quotation marks ("). SO in your case the formula would be:

```
=IF(B5="New Course",25000,"")
```

If B5 is equal to the string New Course, the formula will provide the result 25000, otherwise will return an empty string.

You can find more info on this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)